# why should CSS Spirte image in negative values

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have one doubt do we need to give negative values for CSS Sprite images, i am using a vertical spirte image. Can i give postive values also in this if yes will it work on responsive versions too.

```
background:url(images/test.png) 0 232px/ 100% auto;
```

Comment: Yes positive values can work, too, but it is hard to calculate position this way and harder to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put negative values to `background-position: x y`. Question is... Why you want to place Sprite in not visible area?

---

**Why background-position is negative?**

When you specify `background-position: 0 0` it means that *sprite* image top-left corner is in top-left corner of element. Now that you want to show more inner view of image you have to move your sprite in desired direction according to element. So `background-position-x` mean you are moving *sprite* top-left corner to the right from where your *element* top-left corner is.

Visualization:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.position').text('Left: 50px; Top: 50px;');
            $('.window, .wrapper').css({'background-position': '50px 50px'});
        }, 0);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.position').text('Left: -50px; Top: -50px;');
            $('.window, .wrapper').css({'background-position': '-50px -50px'});
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.position').text('Left: -50px; Top: 0px;');
            $('.window, .wrapper').css({'background-position': '-50px 0px'});
        }, 2000);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.position').text('Left: 50px; Top: 0px;');
            $('.window, .wrapper').css({'background-position': '50px 0px'});
        }, 3000);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.position').text('Left: 0px; Top: 0px;');
            $('.window, .wrapper').css({'background-position': '0px 0px'});
        }, 4000);
    }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/technics/9/') no-repeat;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.window {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 3px dotted #888;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #888;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/technics/9/') no-repeat;
}
.position {
  background-color: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.position:before {
  content: 'Position: ';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Real image:
<br/>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/technics/9/" />
<hr/>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="window"></div>
  <div class="position"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) It will be visible i said its a vertical image so if i change the background position y to negative or positive it doesn't matter it will work. but my question is if you search for spirte image examples it will show some neagtive values thats why i raised a question, i am a newbie in CSS spirte

Comment: @Raju Check my update why you have to specify *inverted* coordinates for background position.